# AttributeError: type object 'DeleteAccount' has no attribute 'DAccount'

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2, attributeerror

I'm using Python 2.7, webapp2 and GAE for developing a web app.
I'm facing a problem which i don't understand, since I know what it means but everything I did seems correct.

I get the error

> AttributeError: type object 'DeleteAccount' has no attribute 'DAccount'

when i try to access the URL myappdomain/DeleteAccount/

I imported in the main file the python file DeleteAccount.py

```
import DeleteAccount
```

I linked the URL with the relative class DAccount of DeleteAccount

```
webapp2.Route(r'/DeleteAccount/',DeleteAccount.DAccount)
```

That's my DeleteAccount.py file

```
import logging
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions
import datastore
import FBLogin

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def dispatch(self):
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
    try:
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def session(self):
    return self.session_store.get_session()



class DAccount(BaseHandler):   
  def get(self):
    w = self.response.write
    logging.info("deleting account")
    w('I've deleted the account')
```

What's wrong? I did what I've done with every other module and everything has worked well with them

Comment: I'd be good to show the entire traceback...

Comment: Try `webapp2.Route(r'/DeleteAccount/', handler=DeleteAccount.DAccount)` and/or `webapp2.Route(r'/DeleteAccount/', handler='DeleteAccount.DAccount')` (no import necessary for the 2nd one - lazy loading).

Comment: I solved copying an existing module, renaming it and rewriting and renaming the methods and the class